# Hibernate cache strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, ehcache, second-level-cache

How do I decide which `CacheConcurrencyStrategy` to use?

- `NonstrictReadWriteCache`,
- `ReadOnlyCache`,
- `ReadWriteCache`,
- `TransactionalCache`.

I read https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/cache/CacheConcurrencyStrategy.html, but doesn't explain in detail enough.

Comment: The gist of the differences is already covered above. But frankly,when I read the API or the documentation, I still couldn't clearly understand the differences
.Please do check my post [here](http://anirbanchowdhury.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/hibernate-second-level-cache-ehcache/) which describes the differences in further detail. Please have a look and feel free to comment.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache-readonly) does a pretty good job at defining them:

> #### 19.2.2. Strategy: read only
>
> If your application needs to read, but
>   not modify, instances of a persistent
>   class, a read-only cache can be used.
>   This is the simplest and optimal
>   performing strategy. It is even safe
>   for use in a cluster.
>
> #### 19.2.3. Strategy: read/write
>
> If the application needs to update
>   data, a read-write cache might be
>   appropriate. This cache strategy
>   should never be used if serializable
>   transaction isolation level is
>   required. If the cache is used in a
>   JTA environment, you must specify the
>   property
>   `hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class`
>   and naming a strategy for obtaining
>   the JTA `TransactionManager`. In other
>   environments, you should ensure that
>   the transaction is completed when
>   `Session.close()` or
>   `Session.disconnect()` is called. If you
>   want to use this strategy in a
>   cluster, you should ensure that the
>   underlying cache implementation
>   supports locking. The built-in cache
>   providers do not support locking.
>
> #### 19.2.4. Strategy: nonstrict read/write
>
> If the application only occasionally
>   needs to update data (i.e. if it is
>   extremely unlikely that two
>   transactions would try to update the
>   same item simultaneously), and strict
>   transaction isolation is not required,
>   a nonstrict-read-write cache might be
>   appropriate. If the cache is used in a
>   JTA environment, you must specify
>   `hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class`.
>   In other environments, you should
>   ensure that the transaction is
>   completed when `Session.close()` or
>   `Session.disconnect()` is called.
>
> #### 19.2.5. Strategy: transactional
>
> The transactional cache strategy
>   provides support for fully
>   transactional cache providers such as
>   JBoss TreeCache. Such a cache can only
>   be used in a JTA environment and you
>   must specify
>   `hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class`.

In other words:

- **Read-only:** Useful for data that is **read frequently but never updated** (e.g. referential data like Countries). It is simple. It has the best performances of all (obviously).
- **Read/write:** Desirable if your data needs **to be updated**. But it doesn't provide a [SERIALIZABLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#SERIALIZABLE) isolation level, [phantom reads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Repeatable_reads_.28phantom_reads.29) can occur (you may see at the end of a transaction something that wasn't there at the start). It has more overhead than read-only.
- **Nonstrict read/write:** Alternatively, if it's unlikely two separate transaction threads could update the same object, you may use the nonstrict–read–write strategy. It has less overhead than read-write. This one is  useful for data that are **rarely updated**.
- **Transactional:** If you need a **fully transactional** cache. Only suitable in a JTA environment.

So, choosing the right strategy depends on the fact that data are being updated or not, the frequency of updates and the isolation level required. If you don't know how to answer these questions for the data you want to put in cache, maybe ask some support from a DBA.

Comment: @Pascal,  for relibility criteira "Transactional" is the best but perforamce is bad right?    can you elaborate what is JTA environment? Is it EJB?

Comment: No. you can use JTA out-of-EJB-container.

Comment: to use Transactional, need to have cache provider that support it? ehache can be used?  i'm using ehcahe+spring hibernatetemplate+Jpa entity , does that consider JTA environment?

Comment: @cometta I wouldn't say that performance are bad but rather that you get the most overhead with it.

Comment: @cometta No, EHCache doesn't support transactional strategy as documented in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache-compat-matrix

Answer (score 12):

Credits: [Baeldung](https://web.archive.org/web/20170203175305/https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache)

> **READ_ONLY:** Used only for entities that never change (exception is thrown if an attempt to update such an entity is made). It is very
> simple and performant. Very suitable for some static reference data
> that don’t change.
>
> **NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE:** Cache is updated after a transaction that changed the affected data has been committed. Thus, strong consistency
> is not guaranteed and there is a small time window in which stale data
> may be obtained from cache. This kind of strategy is suitable for use
> cases that can tolerate eventual consistency.
>
> **READ_WRITE:** This strategy guarantees strong consistency which it achieves by using ‘soft’ locks: When a cached entity is updated, a
> soft lock is stored in the cache for that entity as well, which is
> released after the transaction is committed. All concurrent
> transactions that access soft-locked entries will fetch the
> corresponding data directly from database.
>
> **TRANSACTIONAL:** Cache changes are done in distributed XA transactions. A change in a cached entity is either committed or
> rolled back in both database and cache in the same XA transaction.

Answer (score 0):

1. Transactional − Use this strategy for read-mostly data where it is critical to prevent stale data in concurrent transactions, in the rare case of an update.
2. Read-write − Again use this strategy for read-mostly data where it is critical to prevent stale data in concurrent transactions, in the rare case of an update.
3. Nonstrict-read-write − This strategy makes no guarantee of consistency between the cache and the database. Use this strategy if data hardly ever changes and a small likelihood of stale data is not of critical concern.
4. Read-only − A concurrency strategy suitable for data, which never changes. Use it for reference data only.

Hope this clears your doubt!