# nonstrict read/write vs read/write in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Got thru below statement at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache-nonstrict

**If the application only occasionally needs to update data (i.e. if it is extremely unlikely that two transactions would try to update the same item simultaneously)**

What I got from above statement is if developer updates a object in his code, sometime he want to update in second level cache and sometime does not. Right? If yes how he will achieve it in his code. I mean  where he needs to specify in his code that this time he wants to update in cache and other time not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You got it wrong. What this means if that this strategy should be used when the entity is sometimes updated (so read-only does not apply), but that it's extremely unlikely that two concurrent transactions update the same item. For example, if you have thousands of users accessing the data, an one batch regularly update it, this option is the right one to choose: only one transaction updates the items at a time.

Comment: Thanks  JB. Thats what actuaaly i am asking what is the code snippet that specify nonstrict read/write.As per my understanding it should be specified in our program instead of hbm.xml file.. Right?

Comment: No. It's specified in the xml mapping file of the entity, or in the annotation describing the cache strategy for the entity. Why would it be in code?

Comment: Thanks JB. What will happen when  two concurrent transactions update the same item and if we choose  non strict read/write option.Similarily what will happen when  two concurrent transactions update the same item and if we choose  read/write option

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079615/clustered-hibernate-cache-with-ehcache-nonstrict-vs-strict-read-write