# Many concurrent reads + one write cause ObjectNotFoundException due to ehcache

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency, ehcache

I use Hibernate 3.6.8, ehcache 2.4.5 (also tried with latest 2.8.0), jvm 1.6.0_22 on a high traffic site, and sometimes I experience

> ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.example.Foo#123]`

when a new `Foo` (in this case with id 123) is created via the simplest code possible:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
session.save(foo);
```

The reason is that in all pages of this high traffic site I get all `Foo`s like this:

```
session.createQuery("from Foo").setCacheable(true).list();
```

The table storing `Foo`s contains 1000 rows, and the entity is cached in ehcache:

```
<class-cache class="com.example.Foo" usage="read-write" />
```

Other possibly relevant parts of my Hibernate configuration are:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example?characterEncoding=UTF-8</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">60</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">0</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay">1</property>

<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>

<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset">true</property>

<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</property>
<property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
```

The error happens once and then goes away. I suspect that the ehcache query cache is updated with the new entity id (123) id, but the entity cache is not yet updated with the contents of that entity. I reproduce this fairly easily locally using JMeter.

Any idea on how to solve this?

On `Foo` creation the `ObjectNotFoundException` is thrown once. If on the other hand I delete an instance of `Foo` then I constantly (and forever) get `ObjectNotFoundException` for each execution of `.list()`. The stacktrace can be seen at http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dp3HBgDB

Comment: could you please post your ehcache.xml file

Comment: @AshishJagtap: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LdgWiLE0

Comment: And you have verified that the exception is actually thrown when accessing the cache and not the DB? Possibly indirectly through a read-through cache?

Comment: Any foreign key relationships for `Foo`?

Comment: @MagicMan: Yes there are FKs to the `Foo` table but not necessarily to the entries I create or delete in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I had a scenario where an `ObjectNotFoundException` was thrown due to FK'd child attributes(mapped `@ManyToOne` or `OneToMany`) that have been deleted but still by had a ref in the Parent object. Your scenario have an changes to the underlying child collections of `Foo`? Never liked the workaround that we used, marked those child collections like this: `@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)` Left a bad taste in my mouth.

Comment: @MagicMan: I've just reproduced the problem in a `Foo` that has no FKs/dependencies on other objects nor does it belong to any collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mitigate the case where an entity is deleted and then `list()` does not work at all I've caught `ObjectNotFoundException` at a higher level and when this happens I do:

```
session.getSessionFactory().getCache().evictCollectionRegions();
session.getSessionFactory().getCache().evictDefaultQueryRegion();
session.getSessionFactory().getCache().evictQueryRegions();
```

Clearing the 2nd level cache makes the site work again. This of course doesn't prevent the problem from occuring, but it solves the downtime problem of the whole site.

Answer (score 12):

The `read-write` strategy does not guarantee transactionality between the database and the cache, so I think this is what happens when the write occurs:

- the new object Foo is attached to the hibernate session of the write.
- a lazy loading proxy is inserted into the second level cache by the hibernate session associated to the write request.
- The new Foo will be  inserted in the database by that same session, but the insert will take a certain time to be built, flushed and committed.
- meanwhile another request as hit the proxy to load all Foos. It finds the lazy loading proxy in the cache (see the stacktrace `DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad()`), and decides to load the object (`DefaultLoadEventListener.load()`).
- This triggers a Hibernate `load()` of a Foo not yet inserted in the database by the write thread.
- No Foo with that Id is found on the database, so a `ObjectNotFoundException` is thrown.

To confirm this, put an [exception breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066199/eclipse-break-when-exception-is-thrown) on your IDE, to see that at the moment the exception is thrown the object had not yet been inserted in the DB. One way to solve it would be to use the [transactional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837651/hibernate-cache-strategy) strategy.

Comment: I've used `transactional` ehcache once in the past and quickly reverted because all sorts of other inconsistencies occured. After some investigation it turned out that the cause was that my db transaction isolation level is `REPEATABLE_READ` and it should have been `READ_COMMITTED` in order to work well.

Comment: Your explanation makes a lot of sense.

Comment: The explanation seems pretty possible, I just have one objection. The Foo HAS been inserted in db (and probably committed) since we have an ID in place. However the entity cache is not updated yet, causing the other thread to perform a select by id query. The query does not return anything, because the db isolation level is REPEATABLE_READ. And because of this, it will get no result even if the other thread has actually committed the insert.

Answer (score -1):

Taken from the documentation on **[Cache Configuration](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/configuration#dynamically-changing-cache-configuration)**:

```
The following attributes and elements are optional.

timeToIdleSeconds:
Sets the time to idle for an element before it expires.
i.e. The maximum amount of time between accesses before an element expires
Is only used if the element is not eternal.
Optional attribute. A value of 0 means that an Element can idle for infinity.
The default value is 0.

timeToLiveSeconds:
Sets the time to live for an element before it expires.
i.e. The maximum time between creation time and when an element expires.
Is only used if the element is not eternal.
Optional attribute. A value of 0 means that and Element can live for infinity.
The default value is 0.
```

Or you can also go with the alternate options:

**[Data Freshness and Expiration](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/recipes/expiration)**

Comment: My problem is not cache expiration, but the fact that not all cache regions (query cache and entity cache) are quickly updated with the knowledge that something has been put or removed.