# Hibernate 5 + H2 1.4 MVCC + L2 EhCache without JTA: read/write possible when using only one EMF?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, h2, ehcache

How does [hibernate cache strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837651/hibernate-cache-strategy) relate to MVCC/optimistic locking strategy? I'm not using JTA and only have one EntityManagerFactory and want to add a cache to cache read/write stuff across servlet requests.

Is this at all possible or is Hibernate L2 cache too specifically designed for operation in a full JavaEE environment with full JTA support?