# How to return a single object in Spring Boot Rest when querying a list

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-rest

I currently have a simple Spring Boot app set up with two entities - AppUser and Settings. One AppUser has many Settings in a List like so -

**AppUser -**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class AppUser implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "appUser")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private List<Setting> settings = new ArrayList<>();
    // getters and setters ...
```

**Setting -**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "setting")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Setting implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "test_setting_1")
    private Boolean testSetting1;

    @Column(name = "test_setting_2")
    private Boolean testSetting2;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private AppUser appUser;
    // getters and setters ...
```

I'm currently using the repository to return a List of settings by using

```
List<Setting> findByAppUserId(Long id);
```

Which is being called by the controller -

```
@GetMapping("/settings")
public List<Setting> getAllSettings() {
    return settingRepository.findByAppUserId(1001L);
}
```

When I return that via a controller though, I get an array of objects like this -

```
[
  {
    "testSetting1": true
  },
  {
    "testSetting2": true
  }
]
```

What I'd like to return to the front end is a single object with all the settings in it, something like this -

```
{
  "testSetting1": true,
  "testSetting2": true
}
```

I'm curious what's the best way to do this in Spring?

Comment: Can you add the controller method too please? The returned result isn't valid because if you're returning a `List<Setting>`, both "testSetting1" and "testSetting2" properties should be displayed in the JSON object, even if they're not set. They should be initialized with "null" in this case.

Comment: @SebastianI. Sorry, I don't follow. The returned result that I showed above is what I'm currently getting. It's valid, it's just not in the format that i would like. Nothing should need to be set to null. I added in the controller but, all it's doing is calling the repository function I listed.

Comment: Maybe the cache strategy is getting you in trouble. First, try to remove the `@Cache` annotation and see if the actual result is the same with the expected result. And then you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837651/hibernate-cache-strategy) answer and see why this cache strategy could lead to inconsistent data ( @Pascal Thivent answer) because the result you're expecting should be displayed.

Comment: It's normal to have a JSON array since you request a List, I don't see where is the problem. Also, since you have `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` check if you don't have null values.

Comment: @SebastianI. Removing Cache strategy does not work. akuma8 - the problem is that I need all settings in a single json object for the front end. The jackson json property is set specifically to avoid null values

Comment: @ssdev , @akuma8 wanted to say that maybe "testSetting2" from the first element and "testSetting1" from the second element of the list are not set and `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` will eventually stop displaying them.

Comment: If you need a single object don’t request a List.

Comment: @akuma8 thanks for the suggestion. Do you have an example? The problem is that there are many settings to one user, so I need to return multiple settings, hence a list. Can you show code for what you think would work?